# How can I one-hot encode the data which has multiple same values for different properties?

Tags: machine-learning, encoding, data-science

I have data containing candidates who look for a job. The original data I got was a complete mess but I managed to enhance it. Now, I am facing an issue which I am not able to resolve.

One candidate record looks like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgdkV.png

Since ML algorithms cannot work with categorical data, I want to encode this. My goal is to have a candidate record looking like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdYfi.png

What I need to change is to add a new column for each possible value that exists in Knowledge1, Knowledge2, Knowledge3, Knowledge4, Tag1, and Tag2 of original data, but without repetition. I managed to encode it to get way more attributes than I need, which results in an inaccurate model. The way I tried gives me newly created attributes Jscript_Knowledge1, Jscript_Knowledge2, Jscript_Knowledge3 and so on, for each possible option.

If the explanation is not clear enough please let me know so that I could explain it further.

Thanks and any help is highly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I have some understanding of your problem based on your explanation. I will try and elaborate how I would approach this problem. If that is not solving your problem, I may need more explanation to understand your problem. Lets get started.

- For all the candidate data that you would have, collect a master
  skill/knowledge list
- This list becomes your columns
- For each candidate, if he has this skill, the column becomes 1 for his record else it stays 0
- This is the essence of one hot encoding, however, since same skill is scattered across multiple columns you are struggling with autoencoding it.

An alternative approach could be:

- For each candidate collect all the knowledge skills as list and assign it into 1 column for knowledge and tags as another list and assign it to another column instead of current 4(Knowledge) + 2 (tags).
- Sort the knowledge(and tag) list alphabetically within this column.
- Auto One hot encoding after this may yield smaller columns than earlier

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello Vasu, thank you for the response. I am not quite sure how would this approach affect the data. As far as I understand, this would still give me a column for each list, which can be any combination of skills...

Comment: Yes @nedzad, I also expect such behavior. Since you are sorting the list alphabetically, if the candidates containing identical skills irrespective of if it is in knowledge 1 or 2 will be grouped and encoded identical. This will minimise the explosive number of columns. In worst case, you are limited by nchoose5 columns. n is number of knowledge skills. You can adopt some dimension reduction technique if necessary.

Comment: Yes, that's what I understood from your proposal. Anyway, it can be improved depending on the data, but not as much as seek to improve it. Feeding the model with such data would recognize only candidates with exactly the same skills. Those who have one or two different skills would not be recognized as 'similar'. Thank you :)

Comment: Good point, I agree. I think first approach in my answer can take care of that. Do you agree?

Comment: The first approach sounds like a possible solution. I also thought of it before posting this question. Implementation of it is something that is a bit harder to accomplish.

Comment: Hello Vasu, I just want you to know that I managed to solve the issue to get wanted results. It is not the best way, but it works. Thanks for the help. Cheers!

Comment: Glad you got that working and thanks for letting me know. Could you please write your approach as answer here? It might be useful for someone who is stuck save his time. See you around.